# How to make multiple arrays have consistent time dimension? (cf-python)

Tags: python, time, field, data-conversion

I want to convert the time dimension unit from multiple fields (e.g 365_day, proleptic gregorian, noleap) to all have the same time units to allow comparison

```
x = cf.read_field(.... .nc)
y = cf.read_field(.... .nc)
```

The time dimension is within the field being imported but I don't know how to manipulate that - I'm  abit of a python beginner!
At the moment they all have different units so makes it hard to time-based comparison.

Comment: Please, add a complete example of formats and what you call units. You should also show what you tried so far.

Comment: Read up on the datetime module. Convert all the times to datetime objects which are then comparable.